# How can I access my php web pages running on my server from another device?

Tags: php, apache, webserver, mamp, httpd.conf

I am currently using MAMP to allow my php files to be opened in a browser. I can open these files locally on my server by putting my servers IP address in the URL, e.g. http://172.26.10.189/test.php.

But when I try accessing this page from another device the page does not load. I've tried adding inbound rules on my servers firewall to allow connections to port 8080. I've tried modifying the \apche\httpd.conf file with `Listen 172.26.10.189:8080`. I've also tried completely disabling  my firewall to see if anything happened and I still cannot load my webpage from another device.

Does anyone have any other suggestions? or know what I am doing wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should do 4 steps

step1 "Connect both devices to the same network":
`You'll need to connect both devices to the same network. So make sure your mobile phone is connected to the same Wi-Fi network that your computer is using.`

step2 "Find the IP address of your computer":

```
For Windows, you can find the IP address by visiting Control Panel. In the search box, search for "adapter". Click on View Network Connections. Select the active network connection and click View status of this connection. Click Details and the IP address should be found next to IPv4 Address.

For Mac, open the Network Utility. You can find this quickly with Spotlight by typing cmd + space and then start typing "Network". With Network Utility open, your IP address can be found next to the label IP Address.
```

step3 "Find the host name of your computer":

```
If you prefer, instead of using the IP address, you can use the hostname. This might be preferable so you don't have to keep looking up the IP address every time you change networks.

On Windows, click Start. Then right-click on Computer and select Properties. Then click the Computer Name tab.

On Mac, open System Preferences and click Sharing. Look for the text that reads: Computers on your local network can access your computer at: computer-name.local.
```

step4 "Open your mobile browser and visit the IP address or host name ":

```
Using your mobile browser, simply type the IP address or host name into the URL bar. Make sure to include any necessary ports or paths required to view your website.
```

sorry for bad english

Comment: Thanks for your reply! but i'm trying to allow the page to be accessed from any device on the internet. Also, for whatever reason, when I use my computer name instead of the IP address the webpage doesn't display the html, it only displays the correct page when using the ip address or localhost inside the url.

Comment: sorry for if i cant help you <3